# question on src folders in eclipse

Tags: java, android

So, I've been doing android application tutorials and everytime I create a package, for example the helloAndroid tutorial is com.example.android.  When it saves this to src it creates a folder for com, another for example and one last one for android. So it gives me the error "class com.example.android does not exist" because its broken into different folders.

Comment: Or post the answer here so the next guy has a solution and doesn't have to ask again...

Comment: This is 100% normal for Java - name spaces are delineated with folders. If you are seeing the error, it is likely that you forgot to import the relevant class in a source file.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2159655/compile-and-run-this-java-program

Answer (score 2):

I remember being confused about this when I first started learning Java too!

Packages and folders are a weird concept in Java.

A package is a declaration of where your java file lives.

so a package declaration of

```
package com.folder1.folder2.folder3;
```

means your class will live in the folder

```
com/folder1/folder2/folder3;
```

There are some standards applied.  For example, the first part 'com' denotes what kind of code this is.  Company?  Organization?  Java eXtension?   The second part denotes the name of your company or organization.

For example:

```
package org.stackoverflow.utils;
```

Answer (score 0):

Each package will have a folder in the src tree. If you are getting class not found errors in eclipse you can press ctrl + shift + O to fix them.